# CSS3 Animate.css looking strange on firefox

Tags: firefox, css, animation

Im working with animate.css for a bouncein-out simple animation for a login slide.

http://www.freelancing.com.br/

This is the trigger:

```
$('body').on('click', '.actions .login', function(){
    $('#login').removeClass('bounceOutUp');
    $('.overlay').fadeIn(300);
    $('#login').addClass('bounceInDown');

});
$('body').on('click', '#login .close', function(){
    $('#login').removeClass('bounceInDown');
    $('#login').addClass('bounceOutUp');
});
```

and the basic css markup:

```
.animated {
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

@-moz-keyframes bounceInDown {
0% {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-2000px);
}
60% {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transform: translateY(30px);
}
80% {
  -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
}
100% {
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
}
}

@-moz-keyframes bounceOutUp {
0% {
 -moz-transform: translateY(0);
}
20% {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transform: translateY(20px);
}
100% {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-2000px);
}
}
```

I really dont know why this is rolling on at all. The markup is just the same as chrome, and it rolls just fine there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Chrome, the `transition` property is applied to properties inside an `animation` in Firefox.

Remove the `[-moz-]transition` property and your CSS3 animation will work fine in both Firefox and Chrome.

ps. You're missing `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;` in some of your elements.

Comment: No problem, remove the `(-moz|-webkit)-transition` from `.overlay form[role="widget"]` and comment again if you still have issues with the animation. `=]`

Comment: Thanks mate, really good info about the trasitions on ff. I've managed to tweak it out by fully removing it. The animation-duration from .animated was triggering together, not the easing thou.